# How can I add media on an external drive to Jellyfin?

Tags: pi-4, media-server

I've just installed Jellyfin on my Raspberry Pi 4 using [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-jellyfin/). When I try to add a library from my external SSD, I get the error "The path could not be found. Please ensure the path is valid and try again." The path definitely exists and should be read/writable by Jellyfin.

Things I've done already:

1. Created a partition in ext4 on the drive and auto-mounted it in my home directory as `/home/user/ssd`. Within that directory are directories for Movies, Music, etc.
2. Created a new group called media and added user and jellyfin to the group.
3. Recursively changed the ownership and permissions on the ssd folder to grant ownership rights to media group.
4. Restarted Jellyfin service.
5. Tried to add `/home/user/ssd/Movies` as a Jellyfin library but still get the same error.

It can find files in `/home/user` but the problem starts when it gets to /`home/user/ssd`.

Here are the permissions for the `/home/user/ssd` directory:

`drwxrwsr-x 7 user       media     4096 Feb 19 00:52 ssd`

Within home/user/ssd:

`drwxrwx---  2 user      media 16384 Feb 18 17:39 lost+found`

`drwxrwxr-x  9 user      media  4096 Feb 18 23:35 Movies`

`drwxrwxr-x  5 user      media  4096 Feb 19 00:10 Music`

`drwxrwxr-x  6 user      media  4096 Feb 19 00:54 Podcasts`

`drwxrwxr-x 38 user      media  4096 Feb 18 21:05 Series`

Output of `groups jellyfin`, confirming jellyfin user is in media group:

`jellyfin : jellyfin video render media`

What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my own. The problem was that while /home/user/ssd had all of the appropriate permissions, /home/user did not. I'd have to not only make my home directory owned by the media group, but then give it read/write permissions. While having a directory in my home folder for my external storage made sense to me, I remounted it to /media/ssd and made sure /media was also owned by the media group. That fixed it.